# Django view running on Apache fails with OSError: Permision denied

Tags: django, apache

I have a a Django project running on an apache server. I have a view that runs os.listdir() on a mounted directory (/home) and I get an error

**Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home'.**

I have tried to add the directory in the httpd.conf file but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. If I run the command manually under apache user it seems to work.

Anyone have any suggestions????

Comment: This depends on your wsgi script - it could run under its own user - are you using mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like changing SELinux settings solved the problem. It was blocking access to my mounted directories